# Jquery mobile with Android not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using jquery mobile 1.1.1 with android 4.0.3 and phonegap.  Everything seems to be running smoothly and on iOS and the earlier android versions however, on this version of android stuff is displaying incorrectly.  I am dynamically creating an unordered list and then calling `$('#myList ul').listview('refresh');` on it.  However when it displays it looks like this:

[image: before]

Then I click the screen and it flickers and displays as this(notice how I lose the footer):

[image: after]

Is this a bug with android 4.0.3?  Is there a way to get this to display correctly off the bat?

Comment: I faced such a situation last week, and tried loading the list container after a small delay. You could use setTimeout() function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had it today. I don't know if you're in the same case as me, but I used -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden css attribute to "correct" the white flash with previous version of jQuery Mobile. But in the 1.1.1 with PhoneGap, I had the same thing than you.

So if you use it, just remove it ! If not, I'm sorry for you...

Comment: This did it for me...white flash still persists though.  Do you happen to know of a fix for that as well?